# Why there is no devm_vmalloc() in kernel?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

Recent linux kernel provides device managed resource allocation like `devm_get_free_pages()`, `devm_kmalloc()` or `devm_ioremap()`. It allows us to simplify the code while all deallocations are called on module exit.

Altough I can implement it by myself, I wonder why there is no `devm_vmalloc()` yet.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Comment: Perhaps answer is simple: either submit a patch or acknowledge that no one is needed this functionality.

Comment: I can submit a patch, but I don't understand why vmalloc was omited while devm support for another allocation methods was implemented.

Comment: I believe the question was downvoted because the answer may be opinion-based (I don't think this is the case, though). The question itself is good, but I doubt you will get answer here, it's hard to guess the motivation behind that decision. I would advice you to ask this question on [linux-kernel](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#linux-kernel) mailing list. Also add all persons appeared in [this](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=64c862a839a8db2c02bbaa88b923d13e1208919d) patch (both in "Cc:" and "Signed-off-by:" fields) to "Cc" list in your mail.

Answer (score -1):

Memory allocated using kmalloc is continuous in ram and for that reason can be mmaped to the user (to create a shared memory between kernel and user for example)
the use of devm_* functions is to report the user using sysfs whats going on in the kernel and the user can use this to do something 
for example in android (that based on linux kernel) one can use ION to map physical address to the user so if one device (camera for example) is reporting the address other device (GPU for example) can use it but it can be done only for continuous physical memory.
vmalloc allocations are not continuous and thats why the user have nothing to do with it because it can't access the kernel memory and mmap doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is wrong. Devm has nothing to do with sysfs, kmalloc does not need to be continuous etc.

Comment: i just wanted to give my idea for the reason that no devm_vmalloc exists. you are wrong!! kmalloc allocates contiguous physical block and thats why you can map it to the user. devm_* functions main idea is for resource management but also can supply data through sys so in user space i can read it and map it using other device driver (like ION for example)